# Rename [tag:ds-store] to [tag:.ds-store]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[ds-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ds-store) should be renamed to [.ds-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.ds-store)

Answer (score 3):

Let's make this more general.

There are *file names* (only Unix configuration files AFAICT) and *file name extensions*, and it's not clear which of them get the leading dot, and which don't.

In the *file name* category, we have [ds-store](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ds-store) and [bashrc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/bashrc) on one side (the latter is aliased as *.bashrc*), and [.profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.profile) and [.bash-profile](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.bash-profile) on the other.

With *file name extensions*, we have [.cfm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.cfm) and [.mov](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/.mov) against countless others, among  them heavyweights such as [pdf](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/pdf).

---

I propose we *add* the dot to the file names and *remove* it from file name extensions in all tags (as it's really the dot-less *file format*, and less the *filename extension*), for consistency.